# Import file as string at compile time

Tags: typescript, webpack

I'm using Typescript and Webpack. Is it possible to import a file as a string at compile-time, so I don't need the file at run-time?

I.e.

```
import text from "foo.txt";

const a = text;
```

would compile to

```
const a = "contents_of_foo.txt";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Webpack has the concept of *loaders*, which are responsible for, well, loading things. :-)

There's a list of official loaders [here](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/). There's a [`raw-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/raw-loader/) that can load raw files as strings. Once you configure it, you use it just as you showed (though there's no need for the `const`):

```
import a from "foo.txt";
```

Here's the configuration they show in the link above:

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.txt$/i,
        use: 'raw-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

I don't know that it would compile to exactly what you've shown, not least because Webpack will avoid duplicating the text across files if you use `import ... "foo.txt"` in more than one place. But it'll be handled for you so you don't have to read the file explicitly at runtime.